# creating objects within JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm currently trying to create nested objects within this array in Javascript and I'm unsure how to proceed for the deeper levels

I'm currently getting this structure, which has the levels of name and start_date:

```
{"Todd":
  {
    "dates":
      {
        "05/12/2021":
          [
            "123",
            "ABC"
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

But my desired structure would go further into the date level by zones and then jobs within the zone, like so:

```
{"Todd":
  {
    "dates":
      {
        "05/12/2021":
          {
            "zones":
              {
                "ABC":
                  [
                    "job_1"
                  ]
                "123":
                  [
                    "job_2"
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

How would I alter the object as it currently stands to create these two levels within the date level?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  props: { 

  },
  data: {
    rows: [
      {  
          name: "Todd",
          job: "job_1",
          start_date: "05/12/2021",
          zone: "123",
          hours: 37,
          awards: 12
      },
      {  
          name: "Todd",
          job: "job_2",
          start_date: "05/12/2021",
          zone: "ABC",
          hours: 20,
          awards: 8
      }
    ],
  },
  computed: {
      //Keeping grouped data as object instead of flattening so that we can lookup later. Also tracking total here
      numbersByName() {
        return this.rows.reduce((obj,show) => {
          name = show.name,
          zone = show.zone,
          job = show.job,
          date = show.start_date,
          nameDate = obj[name] = obj[name] || {dates: {} },
          dates = nameDate.dates,
          date = dates[date] = dates[date] || [];

          date.push(zone);

          return obj 
        }, {})

      },
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
{{numbersByName}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would do:

```js
const nest = (rows) =>
  rows .reduce (
    (a, row) => {
      const name = a [row .name] || (a [row .name] = {dates: {}})
      const date = name .dates [row .start_date] || (name .dates [row .start_date] = {zones: {}})
      const zone = date .zones [row .zone] || (date .zones [row .zone] = [])
      zone .push (row .job)
      return a
    },
    {}
  )
  
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  props: { },
  data: {rows: [
    {name: "Todd", job: "job_1", start_date: "05/12/2021", zone: "123", hours: 37, awards: 12},
    {name: "Todd", job: "job_2", start_date: "05/12/2021", zone: "ABC", hours: 20, awards: 8}
  ]},
  computed: {
    numbersByName() {return nest(this.rows)},
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
{{numbersByName}}
</div>
```

I move `nest` out to an external function because I think it's easier to reason about and test as a standalone function.

We simply fold our array of inputs into our output by creating `name`, `date`, and `zone` fields if they don't already exist, attaching them to the correct parent as we go.  Then we push our `job` into the `zone`.

If this syntax isn't clear:

```js
      const name = a [row .name] || (a [row .name] = {dates: {}})
```

it's simply a shorthand way of saying

```js
      let name = a [row .name]
      if (!(name)) {
        name = {dates: {}}
        a [row.name] = name
      }
```

And the next three lines are similar.

Comment: Thank you so much. The understanding of what was going on was probably my biggest issue. I see what's happening now and I believe I can scale that out as need be. I appreciate it